# How can we find the number of blocks occupied by a file from userspace

Tags: command-line, file-io, filesystems

How can we find the number of blocks occupied by a file from userspace ? Is there a command to do so or we need to access the inode structure and then fetch the information.

I have searched a lot on the internet but could not find a valid answer. Can you please let me know

Thanks.

Comment: any specific language/ operational system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -s
```

answers this question from command line.

```
stat(2)
```

answers it from C or C++.